# Propagating wave spherical spreading (or geometric spreading) question

Tags: wave-equation

The intensity (power per unit area) of a spherical wave falls off as $1/4\pi r^2$.

My question: *Is that equation correct? Does this mean the wave amplitude falls off as $1/2\pi^{1/2} r$ ?*

I understand the $1/r$ and the $1/2$ but have not seen the $1/\pi^{1/2} $ used.  The sources I have seen only say that the amplitude is inversely proportional to $r$.

See

http://resource.isvr.soton.ac.uk/spcg/tutorial/tutorial/Tutorial_files/Web-basics-pointsources.htm

and

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129128/45664

Comment: "Proportional to" _means_ "up to a non-zero multiplicative constant" (and "inversely" refers to the reciprocal). Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Write this up as an answer and get the bounty--expires monday.

Answer (score 2):

The [inverse square law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law#Example) $I=\frac{P}{4\pi r^2}$ is correct and its proof is astonishingly simple:

Let $P$ be the total power radiated from a point source. Let's assume this does not depend on time. When the wave is spherical then $P$ is constant on every sphere with radius $r$ around the source. Since the only source of $P$ is the source of the wave it is also clear that -due to energy conservation- $P$ does not depend on $r$. Since the surface area of a sphere with radius $r$ is $A=4\pi r^2$ we get
$$
I=\frac{P}{A}=\frac{P}{4\pi r^2}\,.
$$
Note that his law only holds in three dimensions.